# How to convert all images in a batch from rgb to greyscale using average across all channels for each pixel

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have a batch of images with shape `(32, 32, 3, 73257)` each image is 32x32 and I want to convert RGB of each image to greyscale by taking average across each channel. I know there are other ways but my requirement is to take average.

I can not come up with logic that I can apply this average thing to whole batch and then reduce 3 to 1. Can someone help me? I tried looking on StackOverflow and other things but can not find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: Could you please update your question with 1. Some sample data 2. Results you are expecting 3. What you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img_arr.shape

>>> (32, 32, 3, 73257)
```

```py
img_arr = np.average(img_arr, axis= 2).astype(int)
img_arr.shape

>>> (32, 32, 73257)
```

if you want to retain he shape

```py
img_arr = img_arr[..., np.newaxis, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanna average over the 2nd axis(0-indexing), which has the number of channels( = 3)
You can do that with `np.average()`

```
gray_scale = np.average(your_image_array, axis=2)
```

Then to actually plot the image:

```
plt.imshow(gray_scale, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.show()
```